# Fixed footer under scrollpane in css

Tags: html, css

### Context

I am trying to create a page that would adapt to any sort of screen. This page contains a scrollable section and a fixed footer, always visible. I am using the vh (viewport height) so that the page never scrolls, only the content inside the scrollable container.

---

### Problem

I can't seem to get the footer to align perfectly on every screen width and height (large screens down to mobile phones). This [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjBNrV?editors=110) of what I have already tried.

I don't understand why the `width: inherit` of my footer doesn't take the width of the `survey-container`. And it seems that using `height` in vh (scrollable container) and `top` in vh (footer) is not the way to go, but I don't know how to position them such as the *page* never scrolls (only the container).

---

### Code

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well survey">

      <div class="survey-container">

        <h3 class="text-center">Survey</h3>

        <p class="homepage-text text-center">

          Ribs ribs corned strip hamburger landjaeger strip ribs round chuck pancetta cupim steak. Beef jowl boudin swine bacon kielbasa shank drumstick shank doner steak porchetta kielbasa frankfurter. Mignon drumstick drumstick hamburger pancetta corned brisket
          prosciutto shank ribs loin hamburger. Sausage turkey swine flank ribs corned round hock flank picanha kielbasa chuck rump turkey.
          <br>
          <br> Ribs ribs corned strip hamburger landjaeger strip ribs round chuck pancetta cupim steak. Beef jowl boudin swine bacon kielbasa shank drumstick shank doner steak porchetta kielbasa frankfurter. Mignon drumstick drumstick hamburger pancetta corned
          brisket prosciutto shank ribs loin hamburger. Sausage turkey swine flank ribs corned round hock flank picanha kielbasa chuck rump turkey.
          <br>
          <br> Ribs ribs corned strip hamburger landjaeger strip ribs round chuck pancetta cupim steak. Beef jowl boudin swine bacon kielbasa shank drumstick shank doner steak porchetta kielbasa frankfurter. Mignon drumstick drumstick hamburger pancetta corned
          brisket prosciutto shank ribs loin hamburger. Sausage turkey swine flank ribs corned round hock flank picanha kielbasa chuck rump turkey.
          <br>
          <br> Ribs ribs corned strip hamburger landjaeger strip ribs round chuck pancetta cupim steak. Beef jowl boudin swine bacon kielbasa shank drumstick shank doner steak porchetta kielbasa frankfurter. Mignon drumstick drumstick hamburger pancetta corned
          brisket prosciutto shank ribs loin hamburger. Sausage turkey swine flank ribs corned round hock flank picanha kielbasa chuck rump turkey.
          <br>
          <br> Ribs ribs corned strip hamburger landjaeger strip ribs round chuck pancetta cupim steak. Beef jowl boudin swine bacon kielbasa shank drumstick shank doner steak porchetta kielbasa frankfurter. Mignon drumstick drumstick hamburger pancetta corned
          brisket prosciutto shank ribs loin hamburger. Sausage turkey swine flank ribs corned round hock flank picanha kielbasa chuck rump turkey.
          <br>
          <br> Ribs ribs corned strip hamburger landjaeger strip ribs round chuck pancetta cupim steak. Beef jowl boudin swine bacon kielbasa shank drumstick shank doner steak porchetta kielbasa frankfurter. Mignon drumstick drumstick hamburger pancetta corned
          brisket prosciutto shank ribs loin hamburger. Sausage turkey swine flank ribs corned round hock flank picanha kielbasa chuck rump turkey.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="homepage-footer col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          Footer
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <p class="footer-description">
            Affogato saucer arabica Affogato irish lait cultivar acerbic strong blue mocha mazagran sweet frappuccino. Qui decaffeinated flavour galão Shop beans rich Dark to plunger qui trifecta cup sugar. Dripper ristretto redeye wings pot organic spice frappuccino
            cream cup barista Dark pumpkin. Aroma mazagran roast spoon shop flavour Variety Variety spoon robust spoon lait origin. Aftertaste robust single doppio Affogato milk aftertaste percolator Frappuccino siphon macchiato macchiato carajillo.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.well.survey {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 0 0 50px 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: #8591A0;
    height:71vh;
    overflow: auto;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.survey-container {
    margin: 0 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .survey-container {
        margin: 0 50px;
    }
}

.homepage-footer {
    background-color: #303A40;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 80vh;
    width: inherit;
}

.homepage-footer p {
    color: #fff;
}

.footer-description {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your footer has a larger width than `survey-container` because it has a `position: absolute`. This means it takes the width of the closest parent with either `position: absolute` or `position: relative`.

To fix this, make your `.row` class `position: relative`.

(Do note that the `top: 80vh` is then relative to your `.row` class as well, not the top of your document)

Comment: Great, position: relative. on .row fixes the width! Thank you :) Any idea about the height positioning? The higher the window is, the more space there is between the footer and the container...

Comment: That's because `.well.survey` is `height:71vh` and your footer is `top: 80vh`. This means there is  a `9vh` difference. "vh" means it is dependent on the height of the viewport, which means `9vh` is larger if the window is larger. To solve this, you can make your footer `top:71vh` and add  a fixed  `margin-top: 60px`. That 60px is not dependent on viewport height

Answer (score 0):

Could you adjust your script by putting this way, and this is just a guide for you, not to take it as such, and this works in almost all the screens, browsers, and this includes the **dreaded IE 6** too!

You are supposed to look at the `footer` CSS. Where you wanna keep it, put it inside the parent, and add `position: relative` to the parent.

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
body {padding: 0 0 40px;}
p {margin: 0 0 5px; text-align: justify;}
footer {height: 35px; line-height: 35px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%; background-color: #ccf;}
```

```html
<p>This is a fluid body content.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<footer>Footer Here</footer>
```

Comment: The issue in my code is the margin and positioning of the footer compared to the `.survey-container`